# React.js Object.entries().map() not rendering list contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a full stack application, I wrote a backend that returns JSON. The JSON Structure is similar to:

```
{
    "2022-03-04T09:56:33.525Z": [
        "https://amazon-s3-bucket-presigned-key-for-audio-data",
        "https://amazon-s3-bucket-presigned-key-for-animation-data"
    ],
    "2022-03-04T10:05:01.909Z": [
        "https://amazon-s3-bucket-presigned-key-for-audio-data",
        "https://amazon-s3-bucket-presigned-key-for-animation-data"
    ],
    {...}
}
```

There's **x** amount of audio sources, which will each have **y** amount of recordings collected from that source. Each recording from a given audio source is **guaranteed** to be unique to a timestamp, and will **always** have matching animation data. I have verified this to be the case, and the backend output is definitely not the problem here.

In the React.js frontend, I render a list of accordion components from inside an accordianList component. Each accordion element will have the name of the audio source that it's been collected from, and a conditionally displayed dropdown chevron, dependent on whether or not recordings collected from that source exist. When the dropdown chevron is clicked, a list of custom audio players is rendered, each specific to an individual recording entry collected from that source.

```
AccordianList > Accordian * x > AudioEntry * y
```

**The issue**

I had this system working, but made some drastic changes to the data transfer format. I previously transmitted everything in one go- all recordings from all sources. This was quite large, and caused some issues.

Now, after these changes, when I render the `AudioEntry` component the data inside the list does not render. The animation to change the dropdown chevron switches, as too does the dropdown state... However, the `AudioEntry` component does not get rendered at all. I know this for a fact, as when I replace everything inside that element with a `<li>` or `<h1>` tag, it is not displayed. I have console logged the data received, and can confirm it exists and is in the right format.

I tried these two methods for iterating the JSON object:-

```
<div className={classes.accordian_content} aria-expanded={!thisSensorSelected}> 
<ul>
    { Object.entries(dataList).map(([k, v])=> {
        {console.log({k, v})}
        <AudioEntry 
            key={k}
            date={new Date(k).toLocaleString('gb')}
            audioFile={v[0]}
            animFile={v[1]}
            dropdownClicked={thisSensorSelected}
            filePlaying={filePlaying}
            setFilePlaying={setFilePlaying}
        />
    })}
</ul>
</div>
```

Where the console.log outputs exactly what is expected, but the list is not rendered. There are no errors in the developer tools.

The other method I tried was this:

```
{Object.keys(dataList).map(timestamp => {
    <AudioEntry
        key={timestamp}
        date={new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-gb')}
        audioFile={dataList[timestamp][0]}
        animFile={dataList[timestamp][1]}
        dropdownClicked={thisSensorSelected}
        filePlaying={filePlaying}
        setFilePlaying={setFilePlaying}
    />
})}
```

Again, console.log displays exactly what I expected- but the element is not rendered (which is just a `<li>` at this point).

For sake of clarity, I retrieve the data using an Axios wrapper, called inside an async useEffect function.

Things I have tried:

- Checking whether the `dataList` is empty first (using ternary)
- Object.values
- Placing the Object.values/Object.keys/Object.entries inside of a fragment.
- Placing the entire `<ul>` inside a fragment
- Changing the `thisSensorSelected` state prop to not include `!`
- Banging my head off of the keyboard

Comment: Your map callback doesn't _return_ anything.

Comment: you're missing the `return` keyword

Comment: Use either a) `.map(item => <Component />)` or b) `.map(item => { ... return <Component />; })`

Comment: Thank you! How did I miss this, read documentation and even found that question from earlier. 

Problem is resolved.